# Is it possible to use aws amplify with just openid connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-amplify

I am creating a nuxtjs application using amplify. I have a separate Identity server (openId connect) already built for authentication purposes. (So I don't want to use cognito auth)

1. I am using appsync API - I want to use the already existing identity server to pass a token to the API
2. I want to use S3 to store user files - for this also I want to use my identity server)

I searched but could not find proper documentation for these options. Is this achievable? If so where can I find the proper config?

Comment: Did you managed to configure it? I'm having the same issue

Comment: No I couldn't do it